# Completed Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recieved task:

Add a method to the User model class called get completed count, which:

• accepts a user as a parameter

• determines the number of TodoItems the User has completed using an aggregate query function

– (Hint: You are looking for the count of TodoItems associated with a specific User where completed:true)

• returns the count

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
     has_many :todo_lists, dependent: :destroy
     has_many :todo_items, through: :todo_lists, source: :todo_items, dependent: :destroy
     validates :username, presence: true

     def get_completed_count
        todo_items.length
    end

  end
```

Does anyone can explain what is complete method does?

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How can complete the task....

Answer (score 7):

so you wrote "accepts a user as a parameter" so you should do the following:

```
def self.get_completed_count(user)
  user.todo_items.where(completed: true).count
end
```

and you can call it:

```
User.get_completed_count(user)
```

but the above code doesn't make any sense because better is to do it as instance method:

```
def get_completed_count
  self.todo_items.where(completed: true).count
end
```

this code will return the same results just on instance.

you can call it:

```
User.find(id).get_completed_count
```

i assume that TodoItem has completed as a boolean(better create a scope and use this scope inside the method instead of `where(completed: true)`).

Comment: I think I'd like to see it implemented as an ActiveRecord association really, merging in a scope from the ToDoItem to limit to completed items. So `User.find(id).completed_to_do_items.count`. This would have the benefit of expressing the logic in a single point of the code, while also allowing eager loading in an index page, for example. It would be great to see that approach included in the answer.

Comment: @MichaelHorojanski If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me is:

```
def get_completed_count(user)
       user.todo_items.where(completed: true).count
end
```

Thanks to all for replies.

Comment: This is correct answer that helped me... thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually what I did this morning and it worked perfectly for me

```
def get_completed_count 
       todo_items.where(completed: true).count
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me.

def get_completed_count

self.todo_items.where(completed: true).count

end

Answer (score -1):

You'll want an [ActiveRecordAssociation Extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/model/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :todo_items, through: :todo_lists, source: :todo_items, dependent: :destroy do
      def completed
         where(completed: true).count
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@user.todo_items.completed #-> 5
```

---

To give context to `Mantanco`'s answer, the direct answer to your question is to use a *class method*. This is a method *invoked* with the class:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def completed user
      user.todo_items.where(completed: true).count
   end
end
```

This is called using:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@user = User.completed user
```

What you *need* is an *instance method* -- a method which works on an instance of a class:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def completed_items
      todo_items.where(completed: true).count
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@user.completed_items
```

You'll be able to see the difference between class and instance methods here:
http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/